# What is the meaning of "spread" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

This year's interim budget is being regarded as a big spread for farmers.

Does it mean "extent or amount of something" or "a large meal although not in literal sense)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referring to the complete context of paragraph in ['The Hindu Article'](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/the-pm-kisan-challenge/article26261487.ece),

> This year's interim budget is being regarded as a big spread for
>   farmers.

Definitely refers to the second context, a large meal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the second one, as in "a table spread with lots of food"